# Нужно создать программу частотного алфавита

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ооп, visual-c++, c++-cli

Текст состоит из слов, отделенных друг от друга пробелами или знаками препинания.
Описать функцию, формирующую частотный алфавит данного текста в виде массива символов(букв). Исходный текст прочитать из файла, алфавит записать в новый файл. 
Я прочитала ее из файла, но я не знаю, как сделать частотный алфавит и записать все это в новый файл.

```
 #pragma once

namespace Практика7 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::IO;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для MyForm
    /// </summary>

    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {

        String ^My_Str;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;

        //==========================
        MyForm ^A;


    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //

    My_Str = gcnew String("");



        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()

        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected:

    protected:

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;


    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуется переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательный метод для поддержки конструктора - не изменяйте
        /// содержимое данного метода при помощи редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->richTextBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(338, 76);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(94, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"Применить";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(38, 9);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(288, 17);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label1->Text = L"Возвращаение последнего слова в строке";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 76);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(200, 22);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this->richTextBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 189);
            this->richTextBox1->Name = L"richTextBox1";
            this->richTextBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(200, 119);
            this->richTextBox1->TabIndex = 3;
            this->richTextBox1->Text = L"";
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(338, 189);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(94, 23);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 4;
            this->button2->Text = L"Прочитать";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button2_Click);
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(338, 236);
            this->button3->Name = L"button3";
            this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(94, 23);
            this->button3->TabIndex = 5;
            this->button3->Text = L"Применить";
            this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button3_Click);
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this->button4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(338, 285);
            this->button4->Name = L"button4";
            this->button4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(94, 23);
            this->button4->TabIndex = 6;
            this->button4->Text = L"Сохранить";
            this->button4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(38, 47);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(160, 17);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 7;
            this->label2->Text = L"Поле для ввода текста";
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 104);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(80, 22);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 357);
            this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(200, 22);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 9;
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(709, 549);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->richTextBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }


    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        My_Str = this->textBox1->Text;
        this->textBox2->Text = Transform(My_Str);

    }

    // Описать функцию работы со строкой символов,
    //которая возвращает последнее слово строки.
     String ^ Transform(String ^T)
     {
         return T->Substring(T->LastIndexOf(" "));
     }

    //Чтение из файла

    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        StreamReader^ stream = File::OpenText("TextFile1.txt");
        if (String^ s = stream->ReadLine())
            this->richTextBox1->Text = s;

    }

    //Алфавит
    private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        array< String^>^ MyStr;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (MyStr[i] == MyStr[i + 1])
            {
                MyStr[i + 1] = MyStr[i+2];
            }

        }
    }
};
};
```

Comment: Нужно просто посчитать, сколько раз какой символ встретился. Не могли бы вы более узко локализовать проблему, с которой столкнулись?

Comment: Мне нужно вывести все встречающиеся буквы по порядку, т.е. есть предложение "Мама мыла раму" и выводим  вот это"маылру". Я не знаю, как удалить эти буквы или может создать новый массив и в него все буквы вписывать?

Comment: А что вам говорит по этому поводу ваш преподаватель? Мы же можем разрушить весь образовательный процесс своими советами...

Comment: Нужно создай массив char и в него переписывай все новые символ, еще мне посоветовали использовать for_each чтобы не думать о длине массива, но я немного не понимаю, как использовать for_each

Comment: Если ограничиться однобайтными кодировками (виндовая cp1251 как раз такая), то проще всего сделать массив из 256 элементов и использовать символ в качестве индекса.

Answer (score 2):

Исправленная версия:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<cstdbool>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<tuple>

void bubleSort (std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> &);
bool operator>(const std::pair<int, char> &, const std::pair<int, char> &);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream fin{"input.txt"};
    if (!fin.is_open())
        return 1;
    std::ofstream fout{"output.txt"};
    if (!fout.is_open())
        return 1;

    char ch{};
    std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> alfabet('z' - 'a', {0, 0});
    for (int i{}; i < alfabet.size(); ++i) {
        alfabet[i].second = 'a' + i;
    }
    while (fin.get(ch)) {
        if (isalpha(ch)) {
            ch = toupper(ch);
            alfabet[ch - 'A'].first++;
        }
    }
    bubleSort(alfabet);

    for (int i{}; i < alfabet.size() && alfabet[i].first > 0; i++) {
        fout << alfabet[i].second << " ";
    }

    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    std::cout << "All right!\n";
    return 0;
}

void bubleSort(std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> &in)
{
    auto temp = in[0];

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < in.size(); ++i) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < in.size() - i; ++j) {
           if (in[j + 1] > in[j]) {
               temp = in[j];
               in[j] = in[j + 1];
               in[j + 1] = temp;
           }
        }
    }

    return;
}

bool operator>(const std::pair<int, char> &n1, const std::pair<int, char> &n2)
{
    if (n1.first > n2.first)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что "частотный алфавит", должен, как минимум, быть отсортирован по частоте вхождения?

Comment: нужно чтобы это все было на форме, а не в main

Comment: если хотите, чтобы это было на форме - сами и делайте это на форме. Задача форума: помочь вам сделать, а не сделать за вас. Я показываю алгоритм, а вы его адаптируете.

Comment: и да, я не совсем понял про частотный алфавит: просто посмотрел сразу комменты под постом, где был приведен пример. Ща сделаю как надо